# How to create a Button after entering its data in another window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Context: I have two windows: one is the main window in which I create a new button and add it to a StackPanel. My goal is to make a program that when you enter some data (like title, group and image) in another window these parameters go to the main window and are used to create the new button.

Code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Click event of the accept button

    string tituloHabilidad = Convert.ToString(tituloBox.Text);
    string grupoHabilidad = Convert.ToString(claseBox.Text);
    int nivelHabilidad = Convert.ToInt32(nivelBox.Text);
    this.tituloHabilidad = tituloHabilidad;
    this.grupoHabilidad = grupoHabilidad;
    this.nivelHabilidad = nivelHabilidad;
    tituloBox.Text = "";
    claseBox.Text = "";
    nivelBox.Text = "";
    //menu.crearBoton(tituloHabilidad, grupoHabilidad, nivelHabilidad, nuestroIcono);
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
}

private void bHabilidades_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //vent is the calling of the entering data window
        vent.Show();
        //The retorno methods are simply the getters for the parameters of the button
        ImageBrush nuestroIcono = vent.retornoIcono();
        string tituloHabilidad = vent.retornoTitulo();
        string grupoHabilidad = vent.retornoGrupo();
        int nivelHabilidad = vent.retornoNivel();
        //This method below is the method that creates buttons. The parameters are the data introduced in the entering data button
        crearBoton(tituloHabilidad, grupoHabilidad, nivelHabilidad, nuestroIcono);
    }
         //The crearBoton method adds it to the stackPanel
```

Problem: When I click the "accept" button that sets the data entering window to invisible and next I call the method that creates a new button (in main window) a blank button is created, and if I enter new data in the entering data window the new created button has effectively the correct data (but this data is the old one so it doesn't match the actual request)

What the solution should look like: I think I need an "if" conditional to run the create button method after the getting data method. However I accept whichever solution you make if the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> vent.Show()

doesn't block execution of thread, so without waiting for response it just proceeds to next line. You can change it like this :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Click event of the accept button

    //string tituloHabilidad = Convert.ToString(tituloBox.Text);
    //string grupoHabilidad = Convert.ToString(claseBox.Text);
    //int nivelHabilidad = Convert.ToInt32(nivelBox.Text);
    //this.tituloHabilidad = tituloHabilidad; // basically setting this.x = x; does nothing
    //this.grupoHabilidad = grupoHabilidad;
    //this.nivelHabilidad = nivelHabilidad;
    //tituloBox.Text = "";
    //claseBox.Text = "";
    //nivelBox.Text = "";
    //menu.crearBoton(tituloHabilidad, grupoHabilidad, nivelHabilidad, nuestroIcono);
    this.DialogResult = true;
}

private void bHabilidades_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //vent is the calling of the entering data window
        // Here is something you need to decide :
        // 1. You create new vent dialog and show it, e.g.
        // var vent = new YourWindowName(); // I recommend personally
        // or 2. set dialogresult to null, but dialog will have prefilled data from before (if dialog was used previously)
        // vent.DialogResult=null;

        if(vent.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //The retorno methods are simply the getters for the parameters of the button
            ImageBrush nuestroIcono = vent.retornoIcono();
            string tituloHabilidad = vent.retornoTitulo();
            string grupoHabilidad = vent.retornoGrupo();
            int nivelHabilidad = vent.retornoNivel();
            //This method below is the method that creates buttons. The parameters are the data introduced in the entering data button
            crearBoton(tituloHabilidad, grupoHabilidad, nivelHabilidad, nuestroIcono);
        }
    }
         //The crearBoton method adds it to the stackPanel
```

Essentially it would wait for dialog result to be true, and only then proceed to create button. If for example you have button cancel on enter info window

```
private void Button_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Click event of the cancel button
    this.DialogResult=false;
}
```

then dialog would close, but no button would be created.

Edit : after some questions you have raised I know where the actual problem is.
Methods `retornoIcono()`, `retornoTitulo()` and `retornoNivel()` are most likely just returning `tituloBox.Text`,`claseBox.Text` and `nivelBox.Text`. Since you're setting their values in local variables and clearing textbox.text afterwards it was always giving you empty.string value (or ''). So to fix that there're few ways :

1. comment out the lines that are clearing textboxes (as I've done above, but that is bad practice even if it works);
2. create private variables in window/form class and adjust methods accordingly (or if you prefer - just set them to public and get rid of methods altogether), e.g.

Option 2 sample : private variables / public methods

```
public class YouWindowName
{
private string tituloHabilida, grupoHabilidad;
private int nivelHabilidad;

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
<...snip...>
tituloHabilidad = Convert.ToString(tituloBox.Text);
grupoHabilidad = Convert.ToString(claseBox.Text);
nivelHabilidad = Convert.ToInt32(nivelBox.Text);
<...snip...>
}

public string retornoTitulo()
{
return tituloHabilidad;
}
// do other analogically
```

Comment: I did the first method that you proposed (creating a new window before the if conditional) and I put the DialogResult in the click methods, but it throws me this exception in the vent.Show() line :                                                                                       " System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed. "                                     I don't have a this.Close() anywhere so I don't know why this exception happens

Comment: Also, what should I put in the if conditional? It's giving me an exception if I match vent.showDialog() to true or false and if I remove that match the program cannot run because of an error

Comment: @Clasher "Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed" - It means that window was closed . So i would recommend just use new instance all the time. Also I updated answer so it checks against true condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your dedication, but after change the code to match your tips (I instance a new var for vent like "var vent = new Ventanal2()" being Ventanal2 the window's name and put inmediately afterwards the vent.Show(), then the if conditional. I put all the variables in private also and remove the excess of code. Now it is giving me this exception in the vent.Show line: "ShowDialog can be called only on hidden windows."

Comment: @Clasher You do not need to do vent.Show() - if(vent.ShowDialog()==true) already does that : it first executes vent.ShowDialog(), and after it gets result it does if(result == true)